# Split information in HTML Table and combine with "header" information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-apps-script

I have a HTML form that includes an HTML table where rows can be added/deleted by the users. I sending this data to a Google Sheet. I want to store the "header" information along with each row in the table on separate lines. For example, if a user fills out the form and submits two rows of data in the table there will be two rows sent to the Google Sheet. Columns A thru T, X, and Y will be the same for each row in the table, but columns U,V, and W will be different.

**The issue I'm running into is that my current code isn't collecting any information in the table except for the first row. After I am able to collect that data I'd like to make sure each row of the table creates a new row in the Spreadsheet.**

I've got this working using the now deprecated UI Service, but I want in the HTML service because of the deprication of the UI Service. Plus, it's prettier.

I've based this off the instructions [here](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/).

Here is my Apps Script

```
    ////////////////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
   /////////////                                          \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
  /////////////         BASE APPS SCRIPT CODE.GS           \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
 /////////////                                              \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
////////////////////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

/**
 * Serves HTML of the application for HTTP GET requests.
 * If folderId is provided as a URL parameter, the web app will list
 * the contents of that folder (if permissions allow). Otherwise
 * the web app will list the contents of the root folder.
 *
 * @param {Object} e event parameter that can contain information
 *     about any URL parameters provided.
 */
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  var document = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  // Retrieve and process any URL parameters, as necessary.

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Carrier RA Authorization Request Form')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    ////////////////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
   /////////////                                          \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
  /////////////  BLOG CODE TO MOVE DATA TO GOOGLE SHEET    \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
 /////////////                                              \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
////////////////////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "CarrierData";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function

/*
function doGet(e){
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  var document = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate();
      template.setTitle('RA Request Form - Retail');
      template.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  // return handleResponse(e);
}
*/

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}


function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = [];
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Code Snippet files as follows

1. CSS
2. HTML

```css
<!-- This CSS package applies Google styling;
 it should always be included. --> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css"> <style> .result-display {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 125%;
}
.error {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<!--------------- ADD ROWS CSS ---------------------------> .entry:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.glyphicon {
  font-size: 12px;
}
<!--------------------------------------------------------> input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import common stylesheet. -->
<?!=H tmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile( 'Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>

  <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--------------- BOOTSTRAP CSS --------------------------->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-------------------------------------------------------->
    <script>
      /**
       * Run initializations on web app load.
       */
      $(function() {
        // Call the server here to retrieve any information needed to build the page.
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(contents) {
            // Respond to success conditions here.
            updateDisplay(contents);
          })
          .withFailureHandler(function(msg) {
            // Respond to failure conditions here.
            $('#main-heading').text(msg);
            $('#main-heading').addClass("error");
            $('#error-message').show();
          })
          .getFolderContents(folderId);
      });

       /// -- table add/remove row --- ////
      $(window).load(function() {
        var i = 1;
        var table_tag = 1;
        $("#add_row").click(function() {
          $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input  name='packNumber" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='WHR Packing Slip Model Number'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='qty" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Quantity'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><select name='reason" + i + "' class='form-control'><option>Defective/Damaged Return</option><option>Good Product Return</option></select></td>");

          $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
          i++;
          table_tag++;
        });
        $("#delete_row").click(function() {
          if (i > 1) {
            $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
            i--;
            table_tag--;
          }
        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <html>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Form Name -->
      <h1>Greenville Return Authorization Request Form for Carrier</h1>

      <!----------------------------------->
      <!--------PRIVACY INFORMATION-------->
      <!----------------------------------->

      <form action="https://script.google.com/a/macros/whirlpool.com/s/AKfycbyf9PgQxWaqFG7Tt7RJOgAh_LomVpW0jqT_KR4bA6uxFq-iBx8/exec" method="post">
        <br>
        <div>
          <p><span class="text-danger"> * </span> Indicates a required field.</p>
          <p>Please read and accept the <a href="http://whirlpoolcorp.com/privacy-united-states/">Whirlpool Privacy Statement</a> prior to filling out this form.</p>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" required="">I accept and acknowledge the Privacy and Security Policy above<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
          </label>
          <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>If you have any questions regarding the form or return process, please send an email to <a href="mailto:KASA_Returns@whirlpool.com">KASA_Returns@whirlpool.com</a>. Thank you.</p>
        <br>




        <!----------------------------------->
        <!--COMPANY NAME AND SOLD TO NUMBER-->
        <!----------------------------------->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <!--Company Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="companyName">Retail Company Name returning the product<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
              </label>
              <input name="companyName" id="companyName" type="text" placeholder="Acme, Inc." class="form-control" required="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Soldto Number -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="soldtoNumber">Customer Sold-to Number</label>
              <input name="soldtoNumber" id="soldtoNumber" type="text" placeholder="123456" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!----------------------------------->
        <!-----CUSTOMER SHIP TO ADDRESS------>
        <!----------------------------------->
        <h3> Customer Ship to Address (shipping point returning product to Whirlpool)</h3>
        <!-- Ship To Company Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="shipToCompanyName">Company<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
          </label>
          <input name="shipToCompanyName" id="shipToCompanyName" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
        <!-- Ship To Street Address 1 -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="shipToStreetOne">Street Address 1<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
          </label>
          <input name="shipToStreetOne" id="shipToStreetOne" type="text" placeholder="Street Address 1" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
        <!-- Ship To Street Address 2 -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="shipToStreetTwo">Street Address 2</label>
          <input name="shipToStreetTwo" id="shipToStreetTwo" type="text" placeholder="Street Address 2" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Ship To City -->
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label for="shipToCity">City<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
            </label>
            <input name="shipToCity" id="shipToCity" type="text" placeholder="City" class="form-control" required="">
          </div>
          <!-- Ship To State -->
          <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <label>State<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <select id="shipToState" name="shipToState" class="form-control" required="">
              <option value="AL">AL</option>
              <option value="AK">AK</option>
              <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
              <option value="AR">AR</option>
              <option value="CA">CA</option>
              <option value="CO">CO</option>
              <option value="CT">CT</option>
              <option value="DE">DE</option>
              <option value="DC">DC</option>
              <option value="FL">FL</option>
              <option value="GA">GA</option>
              <option value="HI">HI</option>
              <option value="ID">ID</option>
              <option value="IL">IL</option>
              <option value="IN">IN</option>
              <option value="IA">IA</option>
              <option value="KS">KS</option>
              <option value="KY">KY</option>
              <option value="LA">LA</option>
              <option value="ME">ME</option>
              <option value="MD">MD</option>
              <option value="MA">MA</option>
              <option value="MI">MI</option>
              <option value="MN">MN</option>
              <option value="MS">MS</option>
              <option value="MO">MO</option>
              <option value="MT">MT</option>
              <option value="NE">NE</option>
              <option value="NV">NV</option>
              <option value="NH">NH</option>
              <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
              <option value="NM">NM</option>
              <option value="NY">NY</option>
              <option value="NC">NC</option>
              <option value="ND">ND</option>
              <option value="OH">OH</option>
              <option value="OK">OK</option>
              <option value="OR">OR</option>
              <option value="PA">PA</option>
              <option value="RI">RI</option>
              <option value="SC">SC</option>
              <option value="SD">SD</option>
              <option value="TN">TN</option>
              <option value="TX">TX</option>
              <option value="UT">UT</option>
              <option value="VT">VT</option>
              <option value="VA">VA</option>
              <option value="WA">WA</option>
              <option value="WV">WV</option>
              <option value="WI">WI</option>
              <option value="WY">WY</option>
            </select>
          </div>


          <!-- Ship To Zip -->
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="shipToZip">Zip Code<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
            </label>
            <input name="shipToZip" id="shipToZip" type="number" pattern="\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?" placeholder="Zip" class="form-control" required="">
          </div>
        </div>


        <!----------------------------------->
        <!--------CARRIER INFORMATION-------->
        <!----------------------------------->

        <!-- Carrier Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="carrierName">Carrier Company Name<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
          </label>
          <input name="carrierName" id="carrierName" type="text" placeholder="Sam's Trucking Company" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <!-- Carrier Outbound Tracking Number -->
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="carrierOBNumber">Carrier Outbound Tracking Number</label>
            <input name="carrierOBNumber" id="carrierOBNumber" type="text" placeholder="06459827" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <!-- Carrier Return Tracking Number -->
          <div class=" col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="carrierReturnNumber">Carrier Return Tracking Number</label>
            <input name="carrierReturnNumber" id="carrierReturnNumber" type="text" placeholder="06459827A" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <!-- Date of Original Shipment -->
          <div class=" col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="shipDate">Date of Original Shipment</label>
            <input name="shipDate" id="shipDate" type="date" placeholder="01/01/2015" class="form-control">
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <!-- RA Requster Name -->
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="requesterName">First &amp; Last Name of RA Requester<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
            </label>
            <input name="requesterName" id="requesterName" type="text" placeholder="John Doe" class="form-control" required="">
          </div>

          <!-- Carrier Phone Number -->

          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
            <input name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" type="tel" placeholder="(555) 123 - 4567 x301" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <!-- Carrier Email Address -->
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" type="email" placeholder="John_L_Doe@email.com" class="form-control">
          </div>

        </div>


        <!----------------------------------->
        <!--------RETURN INFORMATION--------->
        <!----------------------------------->
        <h4>To help speed the processing and accuracy of your return credit, please provide as much of the following information as possible.</h4>
        <h5 class="text-danger"><strong>Delivery SID is required</strong></h5>


        <div class="row">

          <!-- WHR Shipment Number-->
          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            <label for="shipNumber">Shipment Number</label>
            <input name="shipNumber" id="shipNumber" type="text" placeholder="Whirlpool Shipment Number" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <!-- Delivery SID Number -->
          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            <label for="sidNumber" class="text-danger">Delivery SID Number<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
            </label>
            <input name="sidNumber" id="sidNumber" type="text" placeholder="Delivery SID Number" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <!-- Whirlpool Order Number-->
          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            <label for="orderNumber">Whirlpool Order Number</label>
            <input name="orderNumber" id="orderNumber" type="text" placeholder="Whirlpool Order Number" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <!-- BOL Number-->
          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            <label for="bolNumber">BOL Number</label>
            <input name="bolNumber" id="bolNumber" type="text" placeholder="BOL Number" class="form-control">
          </div>

        </div>

        <!----------------------------------------->
        <!-------PRODUCT INFORMATION TABLE--------->
        <!----------------------------------------->
        <h4 class="text-center">Product being returned</h4>
        <h5 class="text-center text-danger"><strong>WHR Packing Slip Model Number and Quantity are required fields</strong></h5>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">
                      Row
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center" required="">
                      WHRPackingSlipModelNumber<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center" required="">
                      Quantity<span class="text-danger"> * </span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                      ReasonforReturningProduct
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>
                      1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name='slipNumber' placeholder='WHR Packing Slip Model Number' class="form-control" required="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name='quant' placeholder='Quantity' class="form-control" required="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <select id="reason" name="reason" class="form-control" required="">
                        <option>Defective/Damaged Return</option>
                        <option>Good Product Return</option>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Last Row</a><a id="add_row" class="pull-right btn btn-default ">Add Row</a>
        </div>

        <!----------------------------------------->
<!--------EXTRA RETURN INFORMATION--------->
<!----------------------------------------->
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <label  for="skids">How many skids or pallets will be returned?</label>
  <input name="skids" id="skids" type="text" placeholder="Skid/Pallet Quantity" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <label  for="weight">Weight of return, if known</label>
  <input name="weight" id="weight" type="text" placeholder="Weight (in pounds)" class="form-control">
</div>

</div>

<!--- submit button -->                    
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <button  name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit"type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-block" action="https://script.google.com/a/macros/whirlpool.com/s/AKfycbw6HV4X1lAa64lzIC18YSrvRZS2_aV8hVRMVL953_ICqIvdtqc/exec" method="post">Submit</button>
  </div>

</div>
<br>
<br>
<!----------------------------->
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might have a simple typo here... `getFolderContents()` is declared _inside_ `doGet()`, because there's no closing brace before it. That would keep the function from being visible to `google.script.run`. (If you open the javascript console in the browser, you'll probably see a related error message.)

Comment: @Mogsdad Just tried that. Didn't help. I actually think that function is an unnecessary leftover from the apps script that is in there by default. I'm going to update the code to remove that.

Comment: Then I suggest stripping the whole lot down to the minimum required to reproduce the problem - it's a tough slog going through recreating the hundreds of lines of code, then needing to fill a form with many required fields, etc.

Comment: Looks like the `getFolderContents()` and `updateDisplay()` functions aren't anywhere in code? also `var document = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');` doesn't seem to be used.  To start to debug this I would sugguest using the `Execution Transcript` and `Logs`(You can add a log message with `Logger.log()`) under the `View` menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you have provided the entire HTML, there is no ending `</form>` tag.  But, you probably inadvertently left that out.  I did find something for adding/deleting.

```
<a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Last Row</a><a id="add_row" class="pull-right btn btn-default ">Add Row</a>
```

But I don't see anything that triggers any code to add or delete anything.

You may need to strip down the HTML to just one input, get that to work, then go from there.  If you have code that is adding a new row, and the `name` attribute doesn't get set with a new and unique name, that would cause a problem.   Also, I'm not sure about using the `action` attribute and the `post` method in your form:

```
<form action="https://script.google.com/a/macros/whirlpool.com/s/ID Here/exec" method="post">
```

I'm not sure how apps Script handles that.  The documentation for submitting a form uses `google.script.run`.  With `google.script.run` Apps Script takes the form object, and converts it to something else, where you can only get data back out if you use the name attribute.  It might be worth trying to use `google.script.run` rather than a post request of the form.

Also, I don't see where the code is processing the form object.  You have a line:

```
var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
```

But then `headRow` isn't used anywhere.  From what I can see, your code isn't using any data at all from the form.  I'm not sure that you are even getting the first row.